# Sets and Vectors. Are sets fast in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, set

Please read the question here - http://www.spoj.com/problems/MRECAMAN/

The question was to compute the recaman's sequence where, `a(0) = 0` and, `a(i) = a(i-1)-i` if, `a(i-1)-i > 0` and does not come into the sequence before else, `a(i) = a(i-1) + i`.

Now when I use vectors to store the sequence, and use the find function, the program times out. But when I use an array and a set to see if the element exists, it gets accepted (very fast). IS using `set` faster?

Here are the codes:

### Vector implementation

```
vector <int> sequence;
sequence.push_back(0);
for (int i = 1; i <= 500000; i++)
{
    a = sequence[i - 1] - i;
    b = sequence[i - 1] + i;
    if (a > 0 && find(sequence.begin(), sequence.end(), a) == sequence.end())
        sequence.push_back(a);
    else
        sequence.push_back(b);
}
```

### Set Implementation

```
int a[500001]
set <int> exists;
a[0] = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= MAXN; ++i)
{
    if (a[i - 1] - i > 0 && exists.find(a[i - 1] - i) == exists.end()) a[i] = a[i - 1] - i;
    else a[i] = a[i - 1] + i;
    exists.insert(a[i]);
}
```

Comment: Please format your code appropriately.

Comment: I tried formatting, it doesnt work. I am new here. @bblincoe

Comment: Yes! I tried it, submitted both the codes, one gives TLE and the other AC. @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: My guess is that there is an error in your Vector Implementation code

Comment: Yeah, there's something broken about having a code block immediately after a numbered list.

Comment: @TanjaV please elaborate or suggest where am i going wrong ?

Comment: @achiever202 Have a look on how your code is formatted now. If you tried, **is** it faster? It's unclear what you're asking for!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yeah, its right. i submitted both the codes, the vector one gives "Time limit Exceeded" and the set one gets accepted within the time limit.

Comment: `O(N²) vs O N log N`.

Comment: You should `insert()` only elements to the set, which aren't contained yet. You're calling `insert()` for every iteration.

Comment: You can actually reduce the cost of lookup/insertion in half by carefully using `insert` and checking the returned variable...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ everytime a unique element will be inserted, so thats not a problem.

Comment: Note that the *vector* implementation uses less memory that the *set* implementation.

Comment: YOur if statement in your Vector implementation looks strange - if (a>0) evaluates to true; find gives you an iterator, so you're not comparing apples with apples. I think that you're getting a timeout due to an error in your code

Answer (score 4):

Lookup in an `std::vector`:

```
find(sequence.begin(), sequence.end(), a)==sequence.end()
```

is an `O(n)` operation (`n` being the number of elements in the vector).

Lookup in an `std::set` (which is a balanced binary search tree):

```
exists.find(a[i-1] - i) == exists.end()
```

is an `O(log n)` operation.

So yes, lookup in a `set` is (asymptotically) faster than a linear lookup in `vector`.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily mean it is "faster". Complexity is about how it scales with size.

Comment: @juanchopanza, if you define _faster_ as _has asymptotically smaller execution time_, then smaller complexity also means faster. I am aware that out of context, this statement is imprecise (wrong even). However, given that the OP states the code with vector timed out, while with set it was quite fast, I can assume that the given `n` is considerably large and the asymptotic behavior is observed.

Comment: Sure, and your answer is clearer now. But given OP claims vector is slower than an array, I suspect they are doing something wrong.

Comment: @juanchopanza, the OP states that the vector is slower than an array **and a set**. I updated the answer though anyway (as you have already seen).

Answer (score 2):

If you can sort the vector, the look up is faster in most cases than in set because it is much more cache friendly.

Comment: I cant sort the vector, because at any query i have to look up for the ith element in the sequence.

Comment: @achiever202 I provided an example in my answer which uses a sorted vector, because you can set aside the last inserted element (which is the only one you have to look up)

Answer (score 1):

There is only one valid answer to *most* "Is XY faster than UV in C++" questions:

**Use a profiler.**

While most algorithms (including container insertions, searches etc.) have a guaranteed complexity, these complexities can only tell you about the approximate behavior for large amounts of data. The performance for any given smaller set of data can not be easily compared, and the optimizations that a compiler can apply can not be reasonably guessed by humans. So **use a profiler** and see what is faster. If it matters at all. To see if performance matters in that special part of your program, **use a profiler**.

However, in your case it might be a safe bet that searching a set of ~250k elements can be faster than searching an unsorted vector of tat size. However, if you use the vector only for storing the inserted values and leave the `sequence[i-1]` out in a separate variable, you can keep the vector sorted and use an algorithm for sorted ranges like `binary_search`, which can be way faster than the set.

A sample implementation with a sorted vector:

```
const static size_t NMAX = 500000;
vector<int> values = {0};
values.reserve(NMAX );
int lastInserted = 0;

for (int i = 1; i <= NMAX) {
  auto a = lastInserted - i;
  auto b = lastInserted + i;

  auto iter = lower_bound(begin(values), end(values), a);
  //a is always less than the last inserted value, so iter can't be end(values)

  if (a > 0 && a < *iter) {
    lastInserted = a;
  }
  else {
    //b > a => lower_bound(b) >= lower_bound(a)
    iter = lower_bound(iter, end(values), b);
    lastInserted = b;
  }
  values.insert(iter, lastInserted);
}
```

I hope I did not introduce any bugs...

Comment: I dunno, inserting into a sorted vector is O(N); inserting into a set is O(log N).  Of course I'd have to actually write and time programs to compare.

Comment: No, i cant sort the vector, because at any query, i have to look up for the ith element in the sequence.

Comment: @achiever202 therefore I told you to store the last found element additionally in a separate variable. You only have to see the last variable you inserted.

Comment: @aschepler yes, on very large scales the set will be faster. But the factor will differ from implementation to implementation, so it's not clear when the set's performance will actually take over. After all, to insert into a set, you have to allocate memory for the new tree node, balance the tree etc, which is *different* (faster? slower? at what scale?) to inserting into a vector (remember to `reserve` before the loop).

Answer (score 1):

For the task at hand, `set` is faster than `vector` because it keeps its contents sorted and does a binary search to find a specified item, giving logarithmic complexity instead of linear complexity. When the set is small, that difference is also small, but when the set gets large the difference grows considerably. I think you can improve things a bit more than just that though.

First, I'd avoid the clumsy lookup to see if an item is already present by just attempting to insert an item, then see if that succeeded:

```
    if (b>0 && exists.insert(b).second)
        a[i] = b;
    else {
        a[i] = c;
        exists.insert(c);
    }
```

This avoids looking up the same item twice, once to see if it was already present, and again to insert the item. It only does a second lookup when the first one was already present, so we're going to insert some other value.

Second, and even more importantly, you can use `std::unordered_set` to improve the complexity from logarithmic to (expected) constant. Since `unordered_set` uses (mostly) the same interface as `std::set`, this substitution is easy to make (including the optimization above.

Here's some code to compare the three methods:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <chrono>

static const int MAXN = 500000;

unsigned original() {
    static int a[MAXN+1];
    std::set <int> exists;
    a[0] = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= MAXN; ++i)
    {
        if (a[i - 1] - i > 0 && exists.find(a[i - 1] - i) == exists.end()) a[i] = a[i - 1] - i;
        else a[i] = a[i - 1] + i;
        exists.insert(a[i]);
    }
    return std::accumulate(std::begin(a), std::end(a), 0U);
}

template <class container>
unsigned reduced_lookup() {
    container exists;
    std::vector<int> a(MAXN + 1);

    a[0] = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= MAXN; ++i) {
        int b = a[i - 1] - i;
        int c = a[i - 1] + i;

        if (b>0 && exists.insert(b).second)
            a[i] = b;
        else {
            a[i] = c;
            exists.insert(c);
        }
    }
    return std::accumulate(std::begin(a), std::end(a), 0U);

}

template <class F>
void timer(F f) {
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << f() <<"\t";
    auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Time: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(stop - start).count() << " ms\n";
}

int main() {
    timer(original);
    timer(reduced_lookup<std::set<int>>);
    timer(reduced_lookup<std::unordered_set<int>>);
}
```

Note how `std::set` and `std::unordered_set` provide similar enough interfaces that I've written the code as a single template that can use either type of container, then for timing just instantiated that for both `set` and `unordered_set`.

Anyway, here's some results from g++ (version 4.8.1, compiled with -O3):

```
212972756       Time: 137 ms
212972756       Time: 101 ms
212972756       Time: 63 ms
```

Changing the lookup strategy improves speed by about 30%<sup>1</sup> and using `unordered_set` with the improved lookup strategy better than doubles the speed compared to the original--not bad, especially when the result actually looks cleaner, at least to me. You might not agree that it's cleaner looking, but I think we can at least agree that I didn't write code that was a lot longer or more complex to get the speed improvement.

---

<sub>1. Simplistic analysis indicates that it should be *around* 25%. Specifically, if we assume there are even odds of a given number being in the set already, then this eliminates half the lookups about half the time, or about 1/4<sup>th</sup> of the lookups.</sub>

Comment: +1 Just wanted to add that your figures show almost exactly 25% improvement due to lookup.

Answer (score 0):

The set is a huge speedup because it's faster to look up. (Btw, `exists.count(a) == 0` is prettier than using `find`.)

That doesn't have anything to do with vector vs array though. Adding the set to the vector version should work just as fine.

Comment: `count` is slower since it has to iterate over the whole vector in all cases. If you really want to find an element, using `count` is less expressive too.

Comment: I'm calling `count` on the set, though. And I don't care where the element is, just whether it exists, for which `count` is expressive enough. That's what makes it better: always use the least expressive function that is sufficient for your task; it makes it more obvious what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

It is classic space-time tradeoff. When you use only vector your program uses minimum memory but you should to find existing numbers on every step. It is slowly. When you use additional index data structure (like a set in your case) you dramatically speed up your code but your code now takes at least twice greater memory. More about tradeoff [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space%E2%80%93time_tradeoff).